# How to upload LaTeX files in editorialmanager when there are folders and hirearchy for the latex files?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, latex

I have submitted a paper in a journal, and in the minor revision email that I received, I am asked to "Please make sure to submit your editable source files (i. e. Word, TeX)."

The thing is, there are a lot of files related to my paper for the latex paper to compile (.tex, .bib, .png, etc) and some of them are inside another folder in the root folder of the paper (for example in the content folder)

But in the uploading section of the editorialmanager, you can only upload files it seems. I tried to zip them altogether and upload that instead, but this website then tries to unzip it!

So what is the proper way for me to upload all of my latex files (all the files that are required for my latex based paper to compile) in editorialmanager? Because I need to upload all the required files for them to be able to compile it properly without a hassle it seems.

Comment: What's the problem with reorganizing the files and putting them in a single folder?

Comment: @AdamPřenosil But is this actually the normal way of uploading it? because there are like 25 .tex files, do I really have to manually upload every single one? not to mention I think there was a limit on number of uploaded files..

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I always like to run a “sanitizing” script on any LaTeX source I upload, removing comments and regularizing figure names, etc. This kind of export script could easily extend to flattening the document into a single file, letting you keep your structure for internal use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an export script to flatten your document to a single file plus images. Several options for doing this were provided as answers to this question on the TeX Stack Exchange:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21838/replace-inputfilex-by-the-content-of-filex-automatically

(As compared to editing your source directly, using a script like this lets you maintain your structure internally, then give the publisher the view they need for their purposes.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want your paper to be published in this outlet, you need to follow their production process. This means concretely that you have to edit your latex files so that you have a completely flat file hierarchy, where you only embed files that exists in the same directory. It is usually not that complicated. I would also create a bibtex file with only the references that they need.